# Software Updater Error hangs system update

Tags: apt, 17.10, software-center, update-manager

I'm currently using Xubuntu 17.10. 
I just finished doing a `sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade` in the terminal with no errors. Then the program "Software Updater" popped up noting I needed to install updates.

Using the program Software Updater, during "Installing Updates", configuring linux-image-extra-4.13.0-46-generic, it states:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
error: cannot read '/dev/sdb': Input/output error.
error: cannot read '/dev/sdb': Input/output error.
error: cannot read '/dev/sdb': Input/output error.
error: cannot read '/dev/sdb': Input/output error.
error: cannot read '/dev/sdb': Input/output error.
error: cannot read '/dev/sdb': Input/output error.
error: cannot read '/dev/sdb': Input/output error.
error: cannot read '/dev/sdb': Input/output error.
```

and the system hangs.

What's wrong & how do I fix it?

**UPDATE (10/1/2018):**

Well, it seems I'm still experiencing this same issue, except with a different hard drive. After performing a `sudo apt-get update` it returned a similar output:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
error: cannot read '/dev/sdd': Input/output error
error: cannot read '/dev/sdd': Input/output error
error: cannot read '/dev/sdd': Input/output error
error: cannot read '/dev/sdd': Input/output error
error: cannot read '/dev/sdd': Input/output error
error: cannot read '/dev/sdd': Input/output error
error: cannot read '/dev/sdd': Input/output error
error: cannot read '/dev/sdd': Input/output error
```

add infinitum 21 times !!!

I had to find out what this '/dev/sdd' was.

Doing the following code:

```
$ lsblk
```

returned this:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  87.9M  1 loop /snap/core/5328
loop1    7:1    0  86.9M  1 loop /snap/core/4917
loop2    7:2    0 180.5M  1 loop /snap/vlc/190
loop3    7:3    0 105.2M  1 loop /snap/bitwarden/10
loop4    7:4    0   198M  1 loop /snap/vlc/365
loop5    7:5    0 184.5M  1 loop /snap/tuxguitar-vs/9
loop6    7:6    0    87M  1 loop /snap/core/5145
loop7    7:7    0  86.7M  1 loop /snap/simplescreenrecorder/1
loop8    7:8    0 104.1M  1 loop /snap/b1freearchiver/1
loop9    7:9    0 114.7M  1 loop /snap/b1freearchiver/2
loop10   7:10   0 195.2M  1 loop /snap/vlc/555
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0   931G  0 part /
sdd      8:48   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdd1   8:49   0   300M  0 part 
├─sdd2   8:50   0   100M  0 part 
├─sdd3   8:51   0   128M  0 part 
└─sdd4   8:52   0 465.3G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  14.5M  0 rom
```

It explains what **"`error: cannot read '/dev/sdd': Input/output error`"** is. Specifically, the error has to do with the **/dev/sdd** drive, which is the 500Gb drive that I was using for Windows, but after upgrading to Xubuntu, I have since erased the 500 Gb drive, and was trying to use it for extra storage. My main drive "**/dev/sda**" is the Terabyte drive that the OS is installed on.

Doing code "`ls -l /dev/disk/by-id`", I get the following result:

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-id
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 30 11:01 ata-HL-DT-STDVD-RAM_GH70N_K36C4C50204 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 30 11:01 ata-WDC_WD10EZEX-00BN5A0_WD-WCC3F1LC6X78 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 30 11:01 ata-WDC_WD10EZEX-00BN5A0_WD-WCC3F1LC6X78-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 30 11:01 ata-WDC_WD10EZEX-00BN5A0_WD-WCC3F1LC6X78-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 30 11:02 ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-083CA1_WD-WMAYUL741442 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 30 11:02 ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-083CA1_WD-WMAYUL741442-part1 -> ../../sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 30 11:02 ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-083CA1_WD-WMAYUL741442-part2 -> ../../sdd2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 30 11:02 ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-083CA1_WD-WMAYUL741442-part3 -> ../../sdd3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct  1 01:39 ata-WDC_WD5000AAKX-083CA1_WD-WMAYUL741442-part4 -> ../../sdd4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 30 11:01 usb-Generic-_Compact_Flash_20100818841300000-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 30 11:01 usb-Generic-_Multi-Card_20100818841300000-0:1 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 30 11:01 wwn-0x50014ee262220653 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 30 11:01 wwn-0x50014ee262220653-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 30 11:01 wwn-0x50014ee262220653-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep 30 11:02 wwn-0x50014ee6ace9a515 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 30 11:02 wwn-0x50014ee6ace9a515-part1 -> ../../sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 30 11:02 wwn-0x50014ee6ace9a515-part2 -> ../../sdd2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep 30 11:02 wwn-0x50014ee6ace9a515-part3 -> ../../sdd3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct  1 01:39 wwn-0x50014ee6ace9a515-part4 -> ../../sdd4
```

Not that it's of any real importance, I curiously began investigating what might be the problem with the sdd drive - does it have some bad blocks? Maybe a bit of dust on the disc platter? a pit? Is it Bricked?

I HAD TO KNOW.

Apparently, the sdd drive has 4 partitions on it. For what I haven't a clue. They are:
sdd1, sdd2, sdd3, sdd4. Yeah, I don't know what they are. Even the File Manager won't read the disc.
So, I tested each partition using the following code "sudo dd if=/dev/**sdd** of=/dev/null count=1" changing the **/dev/sdd** to the partition number, (and it's results):

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdd1 of=/dev/null count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.0271085 s, 18.9 kB/s
```

and

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdd2 of=/dev/null count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 1.51427 s, 0.3 kB/s
```

and

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdd3 of=/dev/null count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 1.70216 s, 0.3 kB/s
```

and

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdd4 of=/dev/null count=1
dd: error reading '/dev/sdd4': Input/output error
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 4.08708 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

A-HA!!! That's the one. The culprit partition causing issues IS **sdd4**. 
I performed a Badblocks non-destructive read-write test on it using the following code:

```
sudo badblocks -b 4096 -c 4096 -s -n /dev/sdd4
```

and it took several hours reporting NO bad blocks. I'm still not sure just what the issue is with this drive "/dev/sdd". So I will be removing it from my system, since it's empty anyways.

Concluding, **I wanted to share what I did to uncover/discover what's up with that hard drive.** It's an older drive, so it's not SMART able.

Thanks for reading all this.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to indicate there might be a problem with your hard drive.

Comment: funny thing. NOW, as of 10/1/2018, I get the same message but with '/dev/sdd'. Posting a more detailed edit.